# dynamic linkbutton on dynamic gridview disapears after clicking once

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCountryRisk" runat="server" SkinID="gridviewSkin" AllowPaging="false"
                                OnRowDataBound="gvCountryRisk_RowDataBound">
                            </asp:GridView>

protected void gvCountryRisk_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    int count = (int)ViewState["Count"];
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text != "&nbsp;")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[i].Text).ToString("N2");
                e.Row.Cells[i].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

                // ----------------dynamic link ----------------

                LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();                  
                lnkView.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[i].ToString();

                string Country = gvCountryRisk.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
                string classfn = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

                ViewState["strClassification"] = classfn;
                ViewState["strCounrty"] = Country;
                int Month = Convert.ToInt16(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
                int Year = Convert.ToInt16(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
                lnkView.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ShowDetails('" + Month + "','" + Year + "','" + Country + "','" + classfn + "')");
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(lnkView);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here , on each column of gridview linkbutton is displayed , I have to do something on click of linkbutton, its achieved but only for first click, on second time linkbutton disappears but value remain in columns as a label

Comment: you can use linkbutton attribute in cs page in rowdata bound and call jaavscript function which is tell you count and count is greater than one so you can dissable this link button as you wish...

Comment: Thank, but I want linkbutton on grid for every click, after first click its not appearing on gridview

Comment: please write which code you have to used in ShowDetails function...

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `linkbutton` is added in `_RowDataBound` event and it is not fired on the linkbutton's postback. Please put bind grid out side `Ispostback` checking. For example

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bindgrid();  // Method to bind grid
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ...

    }
}
```

If further assistance needed , Please provide the grid datasource binding method. And expose where it is called.